# Is there a method to make dictionary lexicographical order ignoring upper and lowercase?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a method to make dictionary lexicographical order ignoring upper and lowercase? Now I know make a dictionary lexicographical order but still confused how to ignore lowercase and uppercase. Here are some codes I have tried.

```
dic={'subject':'math','name':'','PS':'$'}
for key,value in sorted(dic.items()):
    print(key+'='+value)
```

Now I have a result that **PS=$** is in the first, but I wanna it in the middle, like this:

```
name=
PS=$
subject=math
```

Comment: Dictionaries are never lexiographically ordered; the order is arbitrary prior to Python 3.6/3.7, then the order is based remembering the *insertion order*

Comment: But what you're actually asking it seems is "can I pass a key to `sorted()` to ignore the case", the answer is yes of course (like `sorted(dict.items(), key = lambda x: x[0].casefold())`); and you could feed that to an `OrderedDict` to retain the sorted structure

Comment: If you're only looking to get the ordering during printing, you could try something like `for k, v in sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: x[0].lower()):` but obviously, anything that's printed it then thrown away, the original dictionary itself will not have a new order

Comment: @Chris_Rands So the code I write can't make what I print is lexicographical order?

Comment: @roganjosh Yeah, you are totally right. But I am a little confused that what the meaning and function of 'key=lambda x: ' is.

Comment: You can look into [lambda functions](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/anonymous-function). As a super brief explanation, you are saying "I want you to sort by the first item in the tuple - the key - after you cast it to lowercase". The `key` argument will take lambda functions and apply them to allow you to change the default sorting rule

Comment: @roganjosh Very clear! Thank you vert much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.6 and 3.7 the dictionaries are insertion ordered, however it is preferable to use [OderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

[Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dic={'subject':'math','name':'','PS':'$'}
dic_ord = OrderedDict(sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda t: t[0].lower()))

for key,value in dic_ord.items():
    print(key, '=', value)
```

Answer (score 1):

**In-place:** Impossible

**Reason :** Once a key is modified, it won't be possible to retrieve back the original value out of the same old dictionary with the modified key. The only way out here is to store the modified key along with original key.

Create a temporary dictonary, say `dic_lex`.

Store the modified key (*lower-cased*) as `key` and  original key as `value`:

```
dic={'subject':'math','name':'','PS':'$'}
dic_lex={key.lower() : key for key in dic.keys()}
for key in sorted(dic_lex.keys()):
    print(dic_lex[key]+'='+dic[dic_lex[key]])
```

prints:

```
name=
PS=$
subject=math
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sorted` with the dictionary constructor

```
dic = dict(sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: x[0].lower()))
# {'name': '', 'PS': '$', 'subject': 'math'}
```